# Stop Timer When Smartcard or Tag Data Detected

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm new to android and now I'm working on NFC project that needed when `smartcard` / `tag` detected the timer will start and when the "data" in `smartcard` has been read and show to TextView the timer will stop. How could I do that ? I want to use just 1 TextView. So, when `TextView` get the data from `smartcard` like "Hello World" the timer stop.

I really appreciate if you want to fix my coding too. It's really mess up, sorry.

This is how to stop the timer :

```
TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

I already tried :

```
tvNFCContent.setText("NFC Content: " + text); // the textview show tag /smartcard data //

tvNFCContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
tvNFCContent.getText().toString();
String yo = String.valueOf(yo.getText().toString());

if (yo == text){
    TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

```
public class Read extends Activity {


    NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    Tag mTag;
    PendingIntent mPI;
    IntentFilter mFilter[];
    String userData, yo;

    boolean writeMode;
    Context context;
    TextView tvNFCContent, Timer, Low;


    Button start, pause, reset, lap;
    long MillisecondTime, StartTime, TimeBuff, UpdateTime = 0L;
    Handler handler;
    int Seconds, Minutes, MilliSeconds;
    ListView listView;
    String[] ListElements = new String[]{};
    List<String> ListElementsArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.read);


        tvNFCContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        Timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

        handler = new Handler();


        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        mPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);

        IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        mFilter = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected, filter2};


        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        readFromIntent(getIntent());

    }


    /**
     * Read From NFC Tag
     *
     * @param intent
     */
    private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];


                }
            }

            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }
    }

    private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");

        try {
            text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
        }

        tvNFCContent.setText("NFC Content: " + text);


    }


    NdefMessage[] getNdefMessage(Intent intent) {
        NdefMessage[] msgs = null;

        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }

        return msgs;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        setIntent(intent);
        readFromIntent(intent);
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        }

        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ndefdiscovered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {
            mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Smartcard detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);


            NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessage(intent);
            if (messages == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data di dalam kartu kosong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
            userData = new String(payload);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Undefined smartcard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPI, mFilter, null);
    }

    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            MillisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - StartTime;

            UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;

            Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);

            Minutes = Seconds / 60;

            Seconds = Seconds % 60;

            MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 1000);

            Timer.setText("" + Minutes + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", Seconds) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", MilliSeconds));

            handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
}
```

I dont want to use button. Just an automatically, when the TextView show the tag / smartcard data the timer will stop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you compare two Strings. You need to use `equals()`.

So, `if(yo == text)` must be changed like this:

```
if(yo.equals(text)){
    TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

Second of all, you need to declare `tvNFCContent` before using its `setText()`.

So, the order must be:

```
tvNFCContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data); // This must come first.

tvNFCContent.setText("NFC Content: " + text); // Then you can set the text.
// tvNFCContent.getText().toString(); // this part is not necessary because you already have "text" variable somewhere.

String yo = String.valueOf(yo.getText().toString()); // Duplicate names are  not a good naming. Try using "yoStr"(String) and "tvYo"(TextView) or something like that.
```

I can't fully understand you but..

Try this:

```
        if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ndefdiscovered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {
            mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Smartcard detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);

            NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessage(intent);
            if (messages == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data di dalam kartu kosong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else{
                TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
            byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
            userData = new String(payload);

            TextView tvNFCContent = findViewById(R.id.tv_nfc_content);
            tvNFCContent.setText("NFC Content: " + userData);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Undefined smartcard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: What I really mean is the timer is start when the smartcard detected (is already done) but I want to stop the timer when the data in smartcard is read (show in TextView) and the stop. How to do it ?

Comment: I updated.. Still don't get it right. I hope it works fine.